# Simple Web UI builder for backend devs

Tags: html, gui, user-interface, rest, gui-builder

I'm a backend dev who technically knows how to work with html css js... but hates it. Is there a low-code free or OSS tool where I can quickly build or prototype simple web guis for my backend services? Functionality should be something like drag and drop UI components like buttons and form fields, sending rest requests and parsing the JSON or XML responses and displaying them or part of them in tables or lists or generating lists of links based on responses from my services. Doesn't need to be fancy at all, a plain unstyled html look would work just fine as long as the amount of html/css/js that needs to be written is minimized.

Comment: You can have simple. You can have web. You can have drag-and-drop. Now choose two. ;-)

Comment: Ok, doesn't have to be drag and drop if it's simple otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I'm still open for other/better suggestions, however this seems to do the trick: https://github.com/ma-ha/rest-web-ui

Demo: https://mh-svr.de/pong_dev/index.html?layout=main